# how to get a % value after matching same name from 2 different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if someone can help me solve the following problem. Someone has previously helped me on get the % of **dctest/In** value on the same worksheet. But right now, i need to do the same thing but on a different worksheet.

Say Sheet1

[image]

this is copied Sheet1 (1) after taking the %

[image]

```
Sub marco1()

'start making Sheet1 into %
'~~> Add/Remove the text here which you want to ignore
Excludetext = "In,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6"

MyArray = Split(Excludetext, ",")

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Set Column B into %
For i = 1 To LastRow
    boolContinue = True

    For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
        SearchText = UCase(Trim(MyArray(j)))
        If UCase(Trim(ws.Range("A" & i).Value)) = SearchText Then
            boolContinue = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If boolContinue = True Then
        With Range("B" & i)
            .Formula = _
            "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A" & i & _
            ",$A$1:$A$45,0),1,0),1,1,1,'Duplicated_Sheet1')),0,1)/$B$5"
            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End With
    End If
Next i
End sub
```

There is some error showing at the formula, did i make a mistake with the formula? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that the column A/B or column A/C or all three will be in a different worksheet? And shouldn't that formula be in Col J like last time?

Comment: I have edited the pictures, right now, i need to match same thing but in a different worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As String
    Dim SearchText As String, Excludetext As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim boolContinue As Boolean

    '~~> Add/Remove the text here
    Excludetext = "In,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,Test6"

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheetname which has the data
    wsData = "Sheet1"

    MyArray = Split(Excludetext, ",")

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        boolContinue = True

        For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
            SearchText = MyArray(j)
            If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = SearchText Then
                boolContinue = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If boolContinue = True Then
            With ws.Range("B" & i)
                .Formula = _
                "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A" & i & _
                "," & wsData & "!$A$1:$A$11,0),1,0),1,1,TRUE,""" & _
                wsData & """)),0,1)/" & wsData & "!B1"
                .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

When using ADDRESS() for a cell in different sheet, you have to specify additional arguments.

**Straight from Excel's help**

Syntax of ADDRESS Function

```
ADDRESS(row_num, column_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet_text])
```

Where **[sheet_text]** is the name of the sheet which we are referring to. I would recommend reading more about it in Excel Help.

This is the actual formula for say **dctest**

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A7,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11,0),1,0),1,1,TRUE,"Sheet1")),0,1)/Sheet1!B1
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: can i ask u one more question, since for this example, it doesnt really comes to a stop unless there isnt any more perimeters after resultant. I'm very curious what if it is in the case of a column. Is it possible to let the coding stops after the columns has finally come to an end?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you?