# Is it possible for VBA to detect whether the column has no value and stop tabulating its %?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm now able to tabulate the % after matching the values from sheet 1 with sheet 2 with the help of Sid. But now, I'm facing this problem,

The following is an image of a problem that i'm facing currently.

In Image1, it is just some test results to be tabulated into %.
[image]

After much help, i'm now able to tabulate it but if you notice after Column H, the result continues to tabulate because i have set the settings all the way til Column Z.
[image]

I'm required to prepare for tests with more columns that is why i set the set til Column Z. What i'm curious about is, is it possible for me to clear all #DIV/0! when there are no more results?

Thank you once again!

Follow up:
My code is as of below:

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsData As String
Dim SearchText As String, Excludetext As String
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim boolContinue As Boolean

'start making Yield_summary into %
'~~> Add/Remove the text here which you want to ignore
Excludetext = "Split,Grade,Wafer,temp,Qty. In,Qty. Out,Bin1,Bin2,Bin3,Bin4,Bin5,Bin6"

'~~> Change this to the relevant sheetname which has the data
wsData = "Sheet1"

MyArray = Split(Excludetext, ",")

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Set Column B into %
For i = 1 To LastRow
    boolContinue = True

    For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
        SearchText = MyArray(j)
        If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = SearchText Then
            boolContinue = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If boolContinue = True Then
        With ws.Range("B" & i)
            .Formula = _
            "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A" & i & _
            "," & wsData & "!$A$1:$A$50,0),1,0),1,1,TRUE,""" & _
            wsData & """)),0,1)/" & wsData & "!B5"
            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End With
    End If
Next i

'Set Column C into %
For i = 1 To LastRow
    boolContinue = True

    For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
        SearchText = MyArray(j)
        If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = SearchText Then
            boolContinue = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If boolContinue = True Then
        With ws.Range("C" & i)
            .Formula = _
            "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A" & i & _
            "," & wsData & "!$A$1:$A$50,0),1,0),1,1,TRUE,""" & _
            wsData & """)),0,2)/" & wsData & "!C5"
            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End With
    End If
Next i
End sub'
```

Comment: Please only show the relevant bits of code. Dumping your entire code isn't helpful. Also please `format it as code` using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see from [Sid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407633/119775) to your previous question that you are putting a formula in your cells like this:

```
    With Range("B" & i)
        .Formula = _
        "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A" & i & _
        ",$A$1:$A$45,0),1,0),1,1,1,'Duplicated_Sheet1')),0,1)/$B$5"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With
```

You can follow up by checking whether the formula returns an error (e.g. `#DIV/0!`), and if so, remove the formula, since it isn't useful:

```
    If IsError(Range("B" & i)) Then
        Range("B" & i).ClearContents
    End If
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing it unless your values might be changed after writing the formulas. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can check for error conditions with the `iferror` function if you're using 2007 or 2010.  Usage looks like:

```
=iferror(YourFunction,"")
```

This will return your function if it does not evaluate to an error, an empty string if it does.

If you have Excel prior to 2007 you can do the same thing only less efficiently.

```
=if(iserror(YourFunction),"",YourFunction)
```

EDIT

To incorporate in your code which just writes the forumlas for you edit:

```
"=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A" & i & _
            "," & wsData & "!$A$1:$A$50,0),1,0),1,1,TRUE,""" & _
            wsData & """)),0,1)/" & wsData & "!B5"
```

To be

```
"=IFERROR(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(A" & i & _
            "," & wsData & "!$A$1:$A$50,0),1,0),1,1,TRUE,""" & _
            wsData & """)),0,1)/" & wsData & "!B5,"""""")"
```

On a side note I find it much easier to use CHAR(34) to add a double quote when writing formulas.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand how to add it into my code. maybe i add in the codes you can understand what i mean.

Comment: Your sheet must have formulas in it.  Replace "YourFunction" with the formula from your sheet.